# Creating date string for error log

Tags: arduino-uno, time

Well, googling didn't do much to help me here and I'm shocked that something I can do in two lines of code in C#

```
DateTime dateTime;
string text = dateTime.ToLongDateString();
```

is this difficult for Arduino, but how do you get a string version of a date time stamp?

I want the current date and time as a string in this format

> May 4, 2016 17:15:33

Since I can't use any of the C++ includes, like ctime, I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: I found a great library for this very purpose!  https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time

Comment: But I can't get any of the examples to work on an Uno

Comment: Which examples did you try? What results did you get?

Comment: What time do you want to get? The Arduino has no concept of the time, unless you add an RTC module, and then it is down to whatever library the RTC module uses.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. So an additional hardware piece(RTC) is required to capture time? I'll look into that

Comment: That's right. The processor chip costs about $US 2. It doesn't include a real-time clock. If it did, how would you set it? And if it did, you would need a battery on the board to keep it powered when you unplug it from the USB/power. There is no battery there.

Answer (score 1):

You need additional hardware like a RTC for example an [DS1307](https://www.adafruit.com/product/264) or on the other hand an arduino/shield with ethernet or wifi so you could get the time by [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) another option might be DCF77 time via the air - sorry forgot GPS could also be used to get the time .... the rest then should be simple creating a string.